# How to load data fetched via ajax faster?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently data is fetched as an array form PHP script. SO I find that for 40 set of data it take about 20 seconds to load. I guess it's because ajax has to wait till until all the results gathered. If the data set increased to hundreds, I think it's gonna slow sown a lot.

So I did some research on how to decrease the loading time thus come across parallel ajax request. I think it would be helpful, for multiple requests.For single request but hundreds and thousands of data fetched, is there a way to increase the speed?

JS :

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'showAllTutor.php',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.length);
            var j=0;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                j++;
                console.log(data[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP :

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM userinfo,posts WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID AND posts.p_id > '$last_msg_id'";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $json=array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
             $total = $row['reviewPlus']+ $row['reviewNeg'];
             array_push($json,array("name"=>$row['name'],"subject"=>$row['subname'],"subid"=>$row['subID'],"rate"=>$row['pricing'],"dateposted"=>$row['datePosted'],"location"=>$row['location'],"contact"=>$row['phone'],"morning"=>$row['morning'],"afternoon"=>$row['afternoon'],"evening"=>$row['evening'],"postId"=>$row['p_id'],"total"=>$total,"plus"=>$row['reviewPlus'],"user"=>$row['UUID']));                
        }       
    }       
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: You need to profile your code to figure out where the bottlenecks are. I'd guess you have a database without enough indexes on it, but that's speculation and this is a really broad topic.

Comment: @Quentin, yes I did not use indexes in my database reason being, I'm afraid indexing would slow down writing into database?

Comment: @Vani the impact on writes that indexes add is nothing compared to the performance enhancements you get on reads (the impact is actually nothing at all!). Rule of thumb is to add an index on every column that's part of a "where" clause

Comment: @Qualcuno, Thanks for the clarification...I might need to use index now but will that help improve the speed for ajax requests?

Comment: If it improves the speed of PHP page generation, will help there too

Comment: Your `where` condition looks suspicious. Sure you didn't mean `join ... on` ?

Comment: Try to make PHP do as little as possible, and shift most of the looping mechanisms to front end

Comment: Don't use * in your select if you don't need/use the concerned data. Maybe you can also activate HTTP data compression, it may have an impact on large data set.

Comment: Would APC (if not already running) be able to speed up the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading time might be because of multiple loops in your code, *while* loop in php and *for* loop in jquery which increase the execution time,

I suggest you to avoid while loop in your php code collect all data using **fetchAll** statement

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

and make your `$total` calculation in yours jquery *for* loop,

This might help, Happy coding.

Comment: Your right. Furthermore move as much of the php logic to the sql statement. For example your calculation of total. That way, combined with keviveks approach, you can remove your loop and just return your result without looping it and pushing rows to a new array.